# Debugging release-mode binaries in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I have an .exe that crashes in release mode. I want to debug where the crash occurs.

How can I use VC++ to debug a crash in a release-mode .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you have access to the code you can open the workspace in visual studion and debug it by pressing F5 button.

Secondly go through the steps that leads to the crash. At that point of time check the location pointed to by the call stack.

This will give you indication on the funciton or line where crash is occuring.

We are assuming this application was written in VC++. How often are you able to reproduce this issue. Is it like everytime you can reproduce it or how is it.

Comment: I just meant Visual Studion unknowningly i wrote 6.0 also sorry shall edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Visual Studio and attach it to a process to debug.
Also check through the Windows Event Viewer (an often overlooked source of information) for any exceptions that Windows may have caught.